# linking dropdown list option from tkinter into my webbrowser

Tags: python, tkinter, python-webbrowser

so the general idea behind this program is simply an app that i can search in diffrent type of website via replacing it in drop down list:

```
import webbrowser
import tkinter as tk
optionlist=["youtube",
"google",
"amazon",
"ebay"]
root=tk.Tk()
root.title("WEB BROWSER")
root.geometry("600x200")
x=tk.StringVar()
variable = tk.StringVar(root)
variable.set(optionlist[0])

def fb():
    webbrowser.open_new("https://www.facebook.com/")

def yt():
    webbrowser.open_new("https://www.youtube.com/")

def ig():
    webbrowser.open_new("https://www.instagram.com/")

def tw():
    webbrowser.open_new("https://twitter.com/")

def search():
    word=x.get()
    search="https://www.google.com/search?q="+word
    webbrowser.open_new(search)

x=tk.StringVar()
b1=tk.Button(root,text="Facebook",fg="white",bg="#3343BA",command=fb)
b2=tk.Button(root,text="Youtube",fg="white",bg="#FF0422",command=yt)
b3=tk.Button(root,text="Instagram",fg="white",bg="#F7378C",command=ig)
b4=tk.Button(root,text="Twitter",fg="white",bg="#12AED8",command=tw)
b6=tk.Button(root,text="Search",fg="white",bg="#121011",command=search)
b7=tk.OptionMenu(root,variable,*optionlist)
b7.config(width=90, font=('Helvetica', 12))
b7.pack(side="top")
b1.place(x=10,y=70,width=80,height=30)
b2.place(x=100,y=70,width=80,height=30)
b3.place(x=190,y=70,width=80,height=30)
b4.place(x=280,y=70,width=70,height=30)
b6.place(x=307,y=10,width=90,height=50)
b7.place(x=360,y=70,width=200,height=30)
el=tk.Entry(root,textvariable=x)
el.place(x=10,y=10,width=300,height=50)


labelTest = tk.Label(text="", font=('Helvetica', 12), fg='black')
labelTest.pack(side="top")
labelTest.place(x=360,y=105)

def callback(*args):
    labelTest.configure(text="You chose to search in: {}".format(variable.get()))
   
variable.trace("w", callback)
root.mainloop()
```

so, as you see i have a working searching app, and i made a dropdown list with the following (ebay amazon google and youtube)
i got the url for searching in each of them thats not the case,
the problem im facing is how do i bind the choice in tkinter to the platform i want to search in

Comment: Your Q is a bit unclear, could you explain again?

Comment: ill do my best, english aint my native language. so i made this "app" that i enter a string to search, and it searches for me via the links i provided with googlechrome. (initially it was only via google and it worked,) now. i made a droplist which has 4 options, i want to link each option to a diffrent search url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this is what you want:

```
def search():
    word = x.get()
    if variable.get() == 'youtube':
        search="https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query="+word
        webbrowser.open_new(search)
    elif variable.get() == 'google':
        search="https://www.google.com/search?q="+word
        webbrowser.open_new(search)
    elif variable.get() == 'amazon':
        search="https://www.amazon.com/s?k="+word
        webbrowser.open_new(search)
    else:
        search="https://www.ebay.com/sch/"+word
        webbrowser.open_new(search)
```

Just make this change to your function, thanks to the "search technique" used by most sites, even multiple words will work correctly, here.

Hope this helped, do let me know if any errors or doubts.

Cheers

Comment: thanks a lot, and i change it from +x.get() to + word and it worked just fine with mupltiple words